# Need help editing a bit of jquery code that changes price options

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery so forgive me if this seems a like odd. At the moment I have the code below. The price when you `select 1` is `12.99`, when you `select 2` the price is `11.99`and any selection from `3 or over is 10.99`. The numbers get multiplied by the quantity selected. What I need help with is changing when the `base price changes`. I want the price from `1 to 4` to be `12.99`. Then from `5 to 9` to be `11.99` then anything from `10` to be `10.99`. I hope this makes sense.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    var map = [ '12.99', '11.99', '10.99' ];
    jQuery('#payslips-required').change(function(){
        var o = parseInt($(this).val()) < 3 ? jQuery(this).val()-1 : 2;
        jQuery('#price').val(map[o]).addClass('hidden');
        var price = $('#price').val();
        var quantity = $('#payslips-required').val();
        var total = price * quantity;
        jQuery('#total').val(total).addClass('hidden');
    });
});
</script>

<select id="payslips-required">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id="price" /> Each
<br />
<input type='text' id="total" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic if and else , hope it works for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){

var map = [ '12.99', '11.99', '10.99' ];
jQuery('#payslips-required').change(function(){

var val=parseInt($(this).val());
var o=0;
if(val>=1 && val<=4)
o=0;
else if(val>4 && val<=9)
o=1;
else
o=2;

jQuery('#price').val(map[o]).addClass('hidden');
var price = $('#price').val()   
var quantity = $('#payslips-required').val()    
var total = price * quantity;
jQuery('#total').val(total).addClass('hidden');

});
});
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLJLP/)